# Get error dbms_debug.error_communication in dbms_debug.synchronize

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, xdebug, synchronize

I tried to run this code but I get error in the function : dbms_debug.synchronize the error is : dbms_debug.error_communication

Does anyone have an idea why this??
(maybe it becouse the DB configuration debug or something else??)

```
  SELECT dbms_debug.initialize FROM dual;
  exec dbms_debug.debug_on;
  exec dbms_debug.attach_session('000E17520001');


  ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG = TRUE;
  set serveroutput ON;


   DECLARE
    info dbms_debug.program_info;
    bnumber BINARY_INTEGER;
    return_int  BINARY_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
      info.namespace := dbms_debug.namespace_pkgspec_or_toplevel;
   info.NAME      := 'LOOP_TESTER';
    info.owner     := 'MY_USER';
  info.dblink    := NULL;   -- no dblink access
    info.line#     := 6;      -- line we want the break

   return_int:= dbms_debug.set_breakpoint(info,3,bnumber);
   -- check for returned error 
    IF return_int != dbms_debug.success THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Error Setting breakpoint');
   ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('Breakpoint set!');
    END IF;
   END;

   DECLARE      
   runinfo    dbms_debug.runtime_info;      
   retval     BINARY_INTEGER;    
  BEGIN      

    dbms_output.put_line(' dbms_debug.info_getstackdepth ' ||dbms_debug.info_getstackdepth);
    dbms_output.put_line(' dbms_debug.info_getbreakpoint ' ||dbms_debug.info_getbreakpoint);
    dbms_output.put_line('  dbms_debug.info_getlineinfo ' || dbms_debug.info_getlineinfo);
      retval := dbms_debug.synchronize(runinfo,0+dbms_debug.info_getstackdepth +
                                 dbms_debug.info_getbreakpoint +
                               dbms_debug.info_getlineinfo +
                              0 );        
     IF retval = dbms_debug.success THEN
       dbms_output.put_line(' Sync Successful ');
    ELSIF retval= dbms_debug.error_communication THEN
     dbms_output.put_line(' Sync Unsuccessful error_communication' );
    ELSE
       dbms_output.put_line(' sync unsuccessful ERROR = '
                            || retval);
    END IF;
  END;


   SELECT loop_tester(500) FROM dual;



 DECLARE      
  frame      number; 
 varvalue   VARCHAR2(500);   
 retval     BINARY_INTEGER;
  varname    varchar2(32);
  BEGIN       
    varname := 'ctr';
    frame   := 0 ;        
    retval  := dbms_debug.get_value(varname, frame, varvalue, NULL);
   dbms_output.put_line('THE VALUE OF THE variable ' || varname ||
        ' IS ' || varvalue);    
 END;
```

Comment: Are you sure thats a good session ID?

Comment: yes,i got it from
 SELECT dbms_debug.initialize FROM dual;

Comment: Can you upload the entirety of your dbms_output?

Comment: dbms_debug.info_getstackdepth 2
 dbms_debug.info_getbreakpoint 4
  dbms_debug.info_getlineinfo 8
 Sync Unsuccessful error_communication

Breakpoint set!

dbms_debug.info_getstackdepth 2

dbms_debug.info_getbreakpoint 4

dbms_debug.info_getlineinfo 8

Sync Unsuccessful error_communication